# I'm not able to implement the hover dropdown in my navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I have created a navbar using html,css and bootstrap. On hover of the menu items, the dropdown appears, but as soon as I move my cursor to dropdown menu, it disappears. I have tried with display: block. But, not able to implement. Can somebody please help me to troubleshoot this issue. It would be of immense help.

```css
.navbar{
  position:relative;
}

.navbar:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px 12.5px 0 12.5px;
  border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
  left: 55px;
  top: 99%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0) scale(1);
  transform: translateY(0) scale(1);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 337ms ease-in-out;
  transition: -webkit-transform 337ms ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 337ms ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 337ms ease-in-out,-webkit-transform 337ms ease-in-out;
}


nav .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link{
   line-height:59px;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 1s;
  -moz-transition: background-color 1s;
  -o-transition: background-color 1s;
  transition: background-color 1s;
}

nav .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn{
  background-color: #f1c575;
}

nav ul li:hover > .nav-link {
  background-color: #f1c575;
  color: #FFF;
}


nav .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {
  position: relative;
}

nav .navbar-nav .nav-item:hover .nav-link:before {
content: "";
display: block;
border-left: 10px solid transparent;
border-right: 10px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 10px solid #7B8B93;
position: absolute;
left: 35%;
bottom: 0px;
}

/* Navbar Ends */

/* Nav Menu Starts */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none !important;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #7b8b93;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top:20px;
  padding-bottom:40px;
}

nav .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link:hover + .dropdown-content{
  display:block !important; 
}


.dropdown-content li:first-child, .dropdown-content li:last-child{
  font-size:18px;
}

.dropdown-content li a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#fff;
}

/* Nav Menu  Ends*/
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="./index.html">LoGO</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="./index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Capabilities</a>
        <ul class="list-inline dropdown-content">
          <li class="list-inline-item list-left-items">
            <a href="#">Products</a>
            <ul class="open-source">
              <li><a>Magento</a></li>
              <li><a>IBM v9 Commerce</a></li>
              <li><a>Drupal</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="list-inline-item list-right-items">
            <a href="#"> Product Categories</a>
            <ul class="list-categories">
              <li class="one">
                <a href="./eCommerce.html" title="E-Commerce">

                  <img class="make-white" src="./images/aoe_icons_services_order_management.svg" alt="E-Commerce">

                  <span class="service-title">E-Commerce</span>
                </a>
              </li>

              <li class="two">
                <a title="Content Management" href="#">

                  <img class="make-white" src="./images/aoe_icons_webportal.svg" alt="Content Management">

                  <span class="service-title">Content Management</span>
                </a>
              </li>

              <li class="three">
                <a title="Middleware &amp; ESB" href="#">

                  <img class="make-white" src="./images/Plattform1.svg" alt="Middleware &amp; ESB">

                  <span class="service-title">Middleware &amp; ESB</span>
                </a>
              </li>

              <li class="one">
                <a title="Search &amp; Recommendation" href="#">

                  <img class="make-white" src="./images/Search2.svg" alt="Search &amp; Recommendation">

                  <span class="service-title">Search &amp; Recommendation</span>
                </a>
              </li>

              <li class="three">
                <a title="Identity &amp; Access Management" href="#">

                  <img class="make-white" src="./images/aoe_icons_technologies-13.svg" alt="Identity">

                  <span class="service-title">PIM Systems</span>
                </a>
              </li>

              <li class="three">
                <a title="Identity &amp; Access Management" href="#">

                  <img class="make-white" src="./images/aoe_icons_technologies-13.svg" alt="Identity &amp; Access Management">

                  <span class="service-title">Identity &amp; Access Management</span>
                </a>
              </li>

              <li class="one">
                <a title="Development Frameworks" href="#">

                  <img class="make-white" src="./images/aoe_icons_betrieb.svg" alt="Development Frameworks">

                  <span class="service-title">Development Frameworks</span>
                </a>
              </li>

              <li class="two">
                <a title="CRM Systems" href="#">

                  <img class="make-white" src="./images/aoe_icons_crm_2.svg" alt="CRM Systems">

                  <span class="service-title">CRM Systems</span>
                </a>
              </li>

              <li class="three">
                <a title="Databases &amp; Storage" href="#">

                  <img class="make-white" src="./images/aoe_icons_Effiziente_Datenverwaltung.svg" alt="Databases &amp; Storage">

                  <span class="service-title">Databases &amp; Storage</span>
                </a>
              </li>

              <li class="one">
                <a title="Mobile Frameworks" href="#">

                  <img class="make-white" src="./images/aoe_icons_mobile-02.svg" alt="Mobile Frameworks">

                  <span class="service-title">Mobile Frameworks</span>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Solutions</a>
        <ul class="list-inline dropdown-content">
          <li class="list-inline-item list-left-items">
            <a href="#">Solutions</a>
            <ul class="open-source">
              <li class="commerce"><a>Dr.Commerce</a></li>
              <li class="universal"><a>Universal Commerce</a></li>
              <li class="emmerging"><a>Emmerging Techlogies</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="list-inline-item list-right-items">
            <a href="#"> Services & Technologies</a>
            <ul class="list-categories">
              <li class="one">
                <a href="#" title="E-Commerce">

                  <img class="make-white" src="./images/Strategy2.svg">
                  <span class="service-title">Strategy &amp; Consulting</span>
                </a>
              </li>

              <li class="two">
                <a title="Content Management" href="#">

                  <img class="make-white" src="./images/Design1.svg">
                  <span class="service-title">UX &amp; Design</span>
                </a>
              </li>

              <li class="three">
                <a title="Middleware &amp; ESB" href="#">

                  <img class="make-white" alt="Software Architecture" src="./images/aoe_icons_Software_Architektur.svg">
                  <span class="service-title">Software Architecture</span>
                </a>
              </li>

              <li class="one">
                <a title="Search &amp; Recommendation" href="#">

                  <img class="make-white" src="./images/aoe_icons_betrieb.svg">
                  <span class="service-title">Agile Development</span>
                </a>
              </li>

              <li class="two">
                <a title="PIM Systems" href="#">
                  <img class="make-white" alt="Digital Products" src="./images/Digitization2.svg">
                  <span class="service-title">Digital Products</span>
                </a>
              </li>

              <li class="three">
                <a title="Identity &amp; Access Management" href="#">

                  <img class="make-white" alt="Payment &amp; Fulfillment" src="./images/aoe_icons_services_payment.svg">
                  <span class="service-title">Payment &amp; Fulfillment</span>
                </a>
              </li>

              <li class="one">
                <a title="Development Frameworks" href="#">

                  <img class="make-white" alt="Systems Integration" src="./images/Integration1.svg">
                  <span class="service-title">Systems Integration</span>
                </a>
              </li>

              <li class="two">
                <a title="CRM Systems" href="#">

                  <img class="make-white" alt="DevOps &amp; Operations" src="./images/aoe_icons_Continuous_Deployment.svg">
                  <span class="service-title">DevOps &amp; Operations</span>
                </a>
              </li>

              <li class="three">
                <a title="Databases &amp; Storage" href="#">

                  <img class="make-white" alt="Customer Care" src="./images/aoe_icons_Customer_Care.svg">
                  <span class="service-title">Customer Care</span>
                </a>
              </li>

              <li class="one">
                <a title="Mobile Frameworks" href="#">

                  <img class="make-white" src="./images/aoe_icons_mobile-02.svg" alt="Mobile Frameworks">

                  <span class="service-title">Mobile Frameworks</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="two">
                <a title="Portal" href="#">

                  <img class="make-white" alt="Portals &amp; Applications" src="./images/aoe_icons_web_and_mobile_applications.svg">
                  <span class="service-title">Portals &amp; Applications</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="three">
                <a title="CMS Solutions" href="#">

                  <img class="make-white" alt="CMS Solutions" src="./images/aoe_icons_web_content_management.svg">
                  <span class="service-title">CMS Solutions</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="one">
                <a title="Middle Ware" href="#">

                  <img class="make-white" alt="ESB &amp; Middleware" src="./images/Plattform1.svg">
                  <span class="service-title">ESB &amp; Middleware</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="two">
                <a title="CRM Integration" href="#">

                  <img class="make-white" alt="CRM Integration" src="./images/aoe_icons_crm_2.svg">
                  <span class="service-title">CRM Integration</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="three">
                <a title="Identity" href="#">

                  <img class="make-white" src="./images/aoe_icons_technologies_IRM.svg">
                  <span class="service-title">Identity &amp; Access Mngmt</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="one">
                <a title="Search" href="#">

                  <img class="make-white" alt="Search" src="./images/Search2.svg">
                  <span class="service-title">Search</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="two">
                <a title="E-Commerce" href="#">

                  <img class="make-white" alt="E-Commerce" src="./images/aoe_icons_services_order_management.svg">
                  <span class="service-title">E-Commerce</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="three">
                <a title="Mobile Apps" href="#">

                  <img class="make-white" alt="Mobile Apps" src="./images/aoe_icons_web_and_mobile_applications.svg">
                  <span class="service-title">Mobile Apps</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="one">
                <a title="PIM Systems" href="#">

                  <img class="make-white" alt="PIM Systems" src="./images/aoe_icons_technologies-13.svg">
                  <span class="service-title">PIM Systems</span>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <p class="text-center mt-5"><a class="btn btn-custom">View All</a></p>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change this css, This makes the li hoverable and will not hoverout if the cursor moves out of anchor .nav-link

```
nav .navbar-nav .nav-item:hover .dropdown-content{
  display:block !important; 
}
```

```css
.navbar{
  position:relative;
}

.navbar:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px 12.5px 0 12.5px;
  border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
  left: 55px;
  top: 99%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0) scale(1);
  transform: translateY(0) scale(1);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 337ms ease-in-out;
  transition: -webkit-transform 337ms ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 337ms ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 337ms ease-in-out,-webkit-transform 337ms ease-in-out;
}


nav .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link{
   line-height:59px;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 1s;
  -moz-transition: background-color 1s;
  -o-transition: background-color 1s;
  transition: background-color 1s;
}

nav .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn{
  background-color: #f1c575;
}

nav ul li:hover > .nav-link {
  background-color: #f1c575;
  color: #FFF;
}


nav .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {
  position: relative;
}

nav .navbar-nav .nav-item:hover .nav-link:before {
content: "";
display: block;
border-left: 10px solid transparent;
border-right: 10px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 10px solid #7B8B93;
position: absolute;
left: 35%;
bottom: 0px;
}

/* Navbar Ends */

/* Nav Menu Starts */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none !important;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #7b8b93;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top:20px;
  padding-bottom:40px;
}

nav .navbar-nav .nav-item:hover .dropdown-content{
  display:block !important; 
}


.dropdown-content li:first-child, .dropdown-content li:last-child{
  font-size:18px;
}

.dropdown-content li a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#fff;
}

/* Nav Menu  Ends*/
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="./index.html">LoGO</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="./index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Capabilities</a>
        <ul class="list-inline dropdown-content">
          <li class="list-inline-item list-left-items">
            <a href="#">Products</a>
            <ul class="open-source">
              <li><a>Magento</a></li>
              <li><a>IBM v9 Commerce</a></li>
              <li><a>Drupal</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="list-inline-item list-right-items">
            <a href="#"> Product Categories</a>
            <ul class="list-categories">
              <li class="one">
                <a href="./eCommerce.html" title="E-Commerce">

                  <img class="make-white" src="./images/aoe_icons_services_order_management.svg" alt="E-Commerce">

                  <span class="service-title">E-Commerce</span>
                </a>
              </li>

              <li class="two">
                <a title="Content Management" href="#">

                  <img class="make-white" src="./images/aoe_icons_webportal.svg" alt="Content Management">

                  <span class="service-title">Content Management</span>
                </a>
              </li>

              <li class="three">
                <a title="Middleware &amp; ESB" href="#">

                  <img class="make-white" src="./images/Plattform1.svg" alt="Middleware &amp; ESB">

                  <span class="service-title">Middleware &amp; ESB</span>
                </a>
              </li>

              <li class="one">
                <a title="Search &amp; Recommendation" href="#">

                  <img class="make-white" src="./images/Search2.svg" alt="Search &amp; Recommendation">

                  <span class="service-title">Search &amp; Recommendation</span>
                </a>
              </li>

              <li class="three">
                <a title="Identity &amp; Access Management" href="#">

                  <img class="make-white" src="./images/aoe_icons_technologies-13.svg" alt="Identity">

                  <span class="service-title">PIM Systems</span>
                </a>
              </li>

              <li class="three">
                <a title="Identity &amp; Access Management" href="#">

                  <img class="make-white" src="./images/aoe_icons_technologies-13.svg" alt="Identity &amp; Access Management">

                  <span class="service-title">Identity &amp; Access Management</span>
                </a>
              </li>

              <li class="one">
                <a title="Development Frameworks" href="#">

                  <img class="make-white" src="./images/aoe_icons_betrieb.svg" alt="Development Frameworks">

                  <span class="service-title">Development Frameworks</span>
                </a>
              </li>

              <li class="two">
                <a title="CRM Systems" href="#">

                  <img class="make-white" src="./images/aoe_icons_crm_2.svg" alt="CRM Systems">

                  <span class="service-title">CRM Systems</span>
                </a>
              </li>

              <li class="three">
                <a title="Databases &amp; Storage" href="#">

                  <img class="make-white" src="./images/aoe_icons_Effiziente_Datenverwaltung.svg" alt="Databases &amp; Storage">

                  <span class="service-title">Databases &amp; Storage</span>
                </a>
              </li>

              <li class="one">
                <a title="Mobile Frameworks" href="#">

                  <img class="make-white" src="./images/aoe_icons_mobile-02.svg" alt="Mobile Frameworks">

                  <span class="service-title">Mobile Frameworks</span>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Solutions</a>
        <ul class="list-inline dropdown-content">
          <li class="list-inline-item list-left-items">
            <a href="#">Solutions</a>
            <ul class="open-source">
              <li class="commerce"><a>Dr.Commerce</a></li>
              <li class="universal"><a>Universal Commerce</a></li>
              <li class="emmerging"><a>Emmerging Techlogies</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="list-inline-item list-right-items">
            <a href="#"> Services & Technologies</a>
            <ul class="list-categories">
              <li class="one">
                <a href="#" title="E-Commerce">

                  <img class="make-white" src="./images/Strategy2.svg">
                  <span class="service-title">Strategy &amp; Consulting</span>
                </a>
              </li>

              <li class="two">
                <a title="Content Management" href="#">

                  <img class="make-white" src="./images/Design1.svg">
                  <span class="service-title">UX &amp; Design</span>
                </a>
              </li>

              <li class="three">
                <a title="Middleware &amp; ESB" href="#">

                  <img class="make-white" alt="Software Architecture" src="./images/aoe_icons_Software_Architektur.svg">
                  <span class="service-title">Software Architecture</span>
                </a>
              </li>

              <li class="one">
                <a title="Search &amp; Recommendation" href="#">

                  <img class="make-white" src="./images/aoe_icons_betrieb.svg">
                  <span class="service-title">Agile Development</span>
                </a>
              </li>

              <li class="two">
                <a title="PIM Systems" href="#">
                  <img class="make-white" alt="Digital Products" src="./images/Digitization2.svg">
                  <span class="service-title">Digital Products</span>
                </a>
              </li>

              <li class="three">
                <a title="Identity &amp; Access Management" href="#">

                  <img class="make-white" alt="Payment &amp; Fulfillment" src="./images/aoe_icons_services_payment.svg">
                  <span class="service-title">Payment &amp; Fulfillment</span>
                </a>
              </li>

              <li class="one">
                <a title="Development Frameworks" href="#">

                  <img class="make-white" alt="Systems Integration" src="./images/Integration1.svg">
                  <span class="service-title">Systems Integration</span>
                </a>
              </li>

              <li class="two">
                <a title="CRM Systems" href="#">

                  <img class="make-white" alt="DevOps &amp; Operations" src="./images/aoe_icons_Continuous_Deployment.svg">
                  <span class="service-title">DevOps &amp; Operations</span>
                </a>
              </li>

              <li class="three">
                <a title="Databases &amp; Storage" href="#">

                  <img class="make-white" alt="Customer Care" src="./images/aoe_icons_Customer_Care.svg">
                  <span class="service-title">Customer Care</span>
                </a>
              </li>

              <li class="one">
                <a title="Mobile Frameworks" href="#">

                  <img class="make-white" src="./images/aoe_icons_mobile-02.svg" alt="Mobile Frameworks">

                  <span class="service-title">Mobile Frameworks</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="two">
                <a title="Portal" href="#">

                  <img class="make-white" alt="Portals &amp; Applications" src="./images/aoe_icons_web_and_mobile_applications.svg">
                  <span class="service-title">Portals &amp; Applications</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="three">
                <a title="CMS Solutions" href="#">

                  <img class="make-white" alt="CMS Solutions" src="./images/aoe_icons_web_content_management.svg">
                  <span class="service-title">CMS Solutions</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="one">
                <a title="Middle Ware" href="#">

                  <img class="make-white" alt="ESB &amp; Middleware" src="./images/Plattform1.svg">
                  <span class="service-title">ESB &amp; Middleware</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="two">
                <a title="CRM Integration" href="#">

                  <img class="make-white" alt="CRM Integration" src="./images/aoe_icons_crm_2.svg">
                  <span class="service-title">CRM Integration</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="three">
                <a title="Identity" href="#">

                  <img class="make-white" src="./images/aoe_icons_technologies_IRM.svg">
                  <span class="service-title">Identity &amp; Access Mngmt</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="one">
                <a title="Search" href="#">

                  <img class="make-white" alt="Search" src="./images/Search2.svg">
                  <span class="service-title">Search</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="two">
                <a title="E-Commerce" href="#">

                  <img class="make-white" alt="E-Commerce" src="./images/aoe_icons_services_order_management.svg">
                  <span class="service-title">E-Commerce</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="three">
                <a title="Mobile Apps" href="#">

                  <img class="make-white" alt="Mobile Apps" src="./images/aoe_icons_web_and_mobile_applications.svg">
                  <span class="service-title">Mobile Apps</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="one">
                <a title="PIM Systems" href="#">

                  <img class="make-white" alt="PIM Systems" src="./images/aoe_icons_technologies-13.svg">
                  <span class="service-title">PIM Systems</span>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <p class="text-center mt-5"><a class="btn btn-custom">View All</a></p>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```